# Conditional recurring IF script

Tags: php

I am running a simple PHP condition that uses Google Analytics Realtime API.

My script checks active visitors number of my webpage, stores its value onto a variable and compares it with > 10.
If found true, it sends out an email to me, telling me that I have more than 10 visitors.
If found false, it halts.

Since I run this under a cronjob, every minute, once I received more than 10 visitors for more than 1 minute, I received multiple emails.

In order to eliminate this issue, I added an file_put_contents execution that writes a simple file, and a simple condition with file_exists, to check if the file exists.

Now, I get a notification only at the first check that finds my visitors more than 10.

But what about spikes? 
I am looking forward to set an alert like 'warning, you have XX visitors for more than Z minutes' if a cronjob is executed Z times in a row and visitors are > 10.

Im searching for a way to handle this. My first though was to set up another alter that would check time()-filemtime($filename) as an $age, but I would still need to create many instances of it, for 30 mins, 1hr etc.

Any advises?

Comment: Put a counter in the file. Whenever the visitors is high, increment the counter, when it's low set the counter back to 0. Send email whenever the counter is 1 (the first alert) and `Z` (the alert about sustained load).

Comment: You could put the number of visitors in the file as well, and also the maximum during the spike.

Comment: @Barmar so I need to include a filename with a number there or just a plain counter with ++ ? Do you have any similar example of PHP script so I can check it implemented? The Z part is confusing me, rest is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put information in the file so you know the state from the previous run. You can keep a counter of the number of times the visitor count is over the threshold and the maximum number of visitors.

```
$threshold = 100; // Alert when more than 100 visitors
$burst_cycle = 10; // Alert every 10 minutes over the threshold

$json = @file_get_contents("data.json");
if ($json) {
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
} else {
    $data = array('counter' => 0, 'max' => 0);
}
if ($visitors < $threshold) {
    $data = array('counter' => 0, 'max' => $visitors);
} else {
    if ($visitors > $data['max']) {
        $data['max'] = $visitors;
    }
    $data['counter']++;
    // Send alert when we first cross threshold and every $burst_cycle minutes it continues
    if ($data['counter'] == 1 || $data['counter'] % $burst_cycle == 0) {
        send_alert("Heavy load for {$data['counter']} minutes, peak = {$data['max']} visitors.");
    }
}
file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($data));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code @Barmar ! It works just fine. I am wondering if there is a way to store the maximum top number of max visitors in a third variable in json. Is there an easy way?

Comment: The maximum top number would be like `max`, except you never let it decrease. So you only update it when the current visitor count is higher than the old value.

Comment: Well I mean, the max amount of users as a historic record. The max is getting replaced upon every run at this time.

Comment: Aren't you talking about adding another element to the array? It would have different logic, and it would only get replaced when it's higher than the previous value.

Comment: You can add as many elements to the array as you want, and use different criteria to update each of them.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks. I noticed that if counter is 20, an alert is not being sent since 20 % 10 = 2 instead of 0. Is there an way to have it sent at 10,20,30,40,50 etc ?

Comment: `20 % 10 == 0`, `20 / 10 == 2`.

Comment: send_alert is executing at 1 and 10 only for me. 20, 30 etc are not triggering it.

Comment: I just tested it, it should work. Are you sure you're getting counts of 20 and 30? Remember, the counter resets to 0 every time $visitors goes below 100.

Comment: I echoed $data['counter'] % $burst_cycle for 10 - 20 - 30 etc and it returns 0, you are right, however, for some reason, If visitors are continuously more than 100, I dont get the alert. I do use php mail command - if theres any known issues with that.

Comment: Check your mail log to see if the mail is being sent. Also check your spam folder to see if your ISP is filtering the messages.

Comment: Well seems more a cron issue to me. Running it manually, it sends mail just fine, but adding a cronjob, fails to send it. I do use /usr/bin/curl --silent  https://example.com/test.php since it needs to be accessed via curl and via web. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the webserver userid have write permission to the JSON file?

Comment: There are different `php.ini` files depending on whether you run it from CLI or web. Maybe your web configuration doesn't have mail configured properly. Can other web pages send mail?

Comment: Yes they do. I added a php mail on a sample test and it worked just fine even i run it multiple times. Anyway, since this is something outside the scope of this quesiton, I will try to solve it by my own. I would like to thank you for your overall support here and for providing a really wonderful solution.